# Controlled-U gate on IBMQ

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction

I want to construct a following 16x16 matrix (system of four qubits)

$U=\text{diag}(1,1,...,1,e^{-iV},e^{-iV})$

where $V$ is a constant.

So this matrix describe these rotations:

$|1110 \rangle  \to  e^{-iV}|1110\rangle$

$|1111 \rangle \to e^{-iV}|1111\rangle$

No rotation is applied to other computational basis states.

Following the book *Principles of quantum computation and information* I can build this $C^4$-$U$ gate: (with ancillary qubits)

[image]

In my situation, I have to build a $C^3$-$U$ gate, but the procedure is the same.

My problem is when I have to apply this $C$-$U$ that appears in the middle of the $C^3$-$U$ gate.

I don't know how to construct the $C$-$U$ gate so that it performs ONLY the rotation $e^{-iV}$ on `q[0]`, leaving the rest of thee qubits (`q[1]`, `q[2]`, `q[3]`) as they were.

I understand that if I know how to construct the $C$-$U$, I will have the $C^3$-$U$ gate which represents the matrix I want to implement.

Comment: Hi @Álvaro and welcome to QCSE. The main question is how to construct a controlled version of the phase gate $U$, defined as $U(V) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i V} \end{pmatrix}$, am I right? Did I understand the question correctly?

Comment: Does chap 5.1 in this [reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9503016.pdf) help you?

Comment: You should apply $U(V)$ proposed by *Davit* on qubit $q_1$ and controlled by qubits $q_2$ and $q_3$. This will prepare global phase gate controlled by qubits $q_1$, $q_2$ and $q_3$ acting on qubit $q_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your gate $U$ with following circuit (*note that I denoted qubits differently, i.e. qubits $q_0$, $q_1$ and $q_2$ are controlling qubits and $q_3$ is target qubit*):

[image: Circuit]

I will start with description of gates acting on qubits $q_2$ and $q_3$. Gate $U1$ is defined as follows
$$
U1(\theta) =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & \mathrm{e}^{i \theta}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

When gate $U1$ acts on qubit $q_2$ and identity gate $I$ acts on qubit $q_3$, they together 
compose so-called controlled global phase gate denoted by matrix

$$
U1 \otimes I =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \mathrm{e}^{i \theta} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \mathrm{e}^{i \theta} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

This gate changes a phase of $q_3$ only in case $q_2$ is in state $|1\rangle$.

However, we want the gate $U$ to act only in case qubits $q_0$, $q_1$ and $q_2$ are all in state $|1\rangle$. This means that gate $U1$ has to be controlled by qubits $q_0$ and $q_1$ as well. Since there is only gate $U1$ controlled by one qubit, we have to use Toffoli gate (logical AND) to indicate whether both qubits $q_0$ and $q_1$ are in state $|1\rangle$. The result of Toffoli gate is stored in ancila qubit $q_4$ and then used for controlling gate $U1$. Finnaly ancila qubit is uncomputed again by Toffoli gate (because this gate is inverse to itself) back to state $|0\rangle$.

Eventuall, only in case qubits $q_0$, $q_1$ and $q_2$ are all in state $|1\rangle$ (as indicated by $X$ gates in the figure), the gate acts and change the phase as desired.

A matrix describing the circuits is this
$$
U = 
\begin{pmatrix}
I_4 & O_4\\
O_4 & U_1 \otimes I \\
\end{pmatrix}
= \text{diag}(1,1\ \cdots, \mathrm{e}^{i\theta},\mathrm{e}^{i\theta}),
$$
where $I_4$ is 4x4 unit matrix and $O_4$ is 4x4 zero matrix.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Martin Vesely's [answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11579/9459):

Here I want to share an alternative way of implementing `ccu1(t, q[0], q[1], q[2])` gate, where $t$ is some phase. It can be shown that `ccu1` gate can be decomposed in the following way:

```
ccu1(t, q[0], q[1], q[2]) =
```

```
cu1(t/2, q[0], q[1])
cx(q[1], q[2])
cu1(-t/2, q[0], q[2])
cx(q[1], q[2])
cu1(t/2, q[0], q[2])
```

where:

```
cu1(t, q[0], q[1]) =
```

```
u1(t/2, q[0])
cx(q[0], q[1])
u1(-t/2, q[1])
cx(q[0], q[1])
u1(t/2, q[1])
```

As can be found [here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/f38b617748d855e98f682d259b7cf597ef16b2a8/qiskit/extensions/standard/u1.py#L190-L194). So, this implementation of `ccu1` gate will require 17 gates in Qiskit and no ancillary qubit. For the version with the `ccx` gates we will need 35 gates in Qiskit if we will use [this](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/f38b617748d855e98f682d259b7cf597ef16b2a8/qiskit/extensions/standard/x.py#L357-L362) decomposition for `ccx`.

---

**EDIT** (*by Martin Vesely*): For graphical illustration, here is the circuit implementing $U$ on IBM Q for $t = \pi$:

[image: IBM Q implementation]

Comment: Nice solution with no ancilas (+1). Just note that $CU1$ gate is available in QASM and I would expect that in Qiskit as well. So, you can use it directly without further decomposition to simpler gates.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinVesely :). Your proposed solution with the $ccu1$ gate was great. But is the $cu1$ gate implemented at the hardware level? At the hardware level, isn't there just $u1$, $u2$, $u3$ and $cx$ gates for most of IBM's available hardwares?

Comment: But yes, we can use $cu1$ and let the transpiler to do the decomposition part.

Comment: Yes, you are right, $CU1$ is not implemented on HW level but transpiler will replace it by code you posted.